# Set index name when creating it with the MongoDB Ruby Driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, indexing

I'm trying to create an index using the [mongo-ruby-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver).

As stated in [the docs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/docs/tutorials/ruby-driver-indexing.txt#L57) I can add a `name` key in the options to override the default name derived from the indexed keys.

```rb
@mongo_client["orders"].indexes.create_one(
  {
    "foo" => 1,
    "bar" => 1
  },
  {
    "unique" => true,
    "name" => "foobar"
  }
)
```

However it seems to be ignored. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this line https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/index/view.rb#L281 I could assume that your problem is using string keys instead of symbol ones. Try the following instead:

```rb
@mongo_client["orders"].indexes.create_one(
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 1
  },
  unique: true,
  name: "foobar"
)
```